# Can not render web component

Tags: javascript, typescript, web-component

I can not render my web component. I created a class `HelloWC.ts` which has the only one task (render **Hello** inside `<h2>` tag). I used `tsconfig.json` to define how to build */dist* directory which contain `HelloWC` class translated to ***es6***. In `index.html` file, I added `<script>` tag (in the end of the `<body>`) in which I imported my `HelloWC` component from */dist* directory. Then I wanted to render my `<hello-wc>` component inside `index.html` `<body>` tag. If I inspect my `index.html` served by `server-http` I can see that there is a `<hello-wc></hello-wc>` tag but it is empty. In the network card I can also see that HelloWC.js was download successfully. I also added a simple `console.log()` to the constructor of my component but the message is never logged (it looks like my component is never created). I have no idea why my component can not render properly. If you have any idea let me know.

**HelloWC.ts**

```js
const template: string = `<div>
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>`;

export class HelloWC extends HTMLElement {
    shadowRoot!: ShadowRoot;

    public static TAG = 'hello-wc';

    constructor() {
        super();
        console.log('heelo wc');
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open'});
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = template;

    }
}
customElements.define(HelloWC.TAG, HelloWC);
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello WC</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <hello-wc></hello-wc>
        <script src="/dist/HelloWC.js" type="module"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "umd",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src",
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ]
}
```

**Project structure**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are importing the compiled file as ES module, however, `tsconfig.json` you have specified `"module": "umd"` (it should be `es6` or `esnext` not `umd` if you want the ES modules)

Comment: I didn't think of it that way. Thank you:D